# unable to locate openmpi-bin

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox

I'm on windows 10 and I'm using virtualBox to run ubuntu version 22.04.1, I couldn't install openmpi-bin or libopenmpi-dev

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin lipopenmpi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package openmpi-bin
E: unable to locate package libopenmpi-dev
```

I tried all solutions I found on google but none of them worked

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first.

Comment: I already did, I mentioned I tried all solutions I found on google

Comment: Please post output of that command? Are you connected to internet?

Comment: yeah I checked that I connected to internet, someone answered me, thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These packages are available in the `universal` repositories. The instructions for enabling this repo are available here:  [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: That perfectly solved the problem, thank you.